# Display images from Wordpress post in a modal

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog

I've been looking in google and couldn't find a tutorial. I would like that when the user clicks on a image in a wordpress post, a modal opens and displays the image with full size. I don't have an issue on how to make a modal, I'm just not sure how to fetch the image and put it in the modal. I don't want to use a plugin, I want to undertand how it works. If you have a good tutorial on how to do that, or if you feel like explaining it, please do!
Thanks!

Comment: Well you'll want to use something like [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) to get the image once in a small and once in a larger (or full) size ... and then output both in the HTML structure needed for a small image, that triggers a modal with the large one when clicked.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for, maybe I didn't explain very well. I have posts with pictures in it and you can display them in links, but when you click on the image, wordpress takes you to another page where the image is in full size. I would like to not open this page, but display the image in a a modal instead. I don't think your suggestion works for that, does it?

Comment: Well then I'd suggest you make those images inside the post a WP Gallery (https://codex.wordpress.org/The_WordPress_Gallery, if they aren't already), and then go look for a "lightbox" or "fancybox" plugin that works with the gallery: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/gallery/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a JS onclick function ex openModal() that submits current post info as arguments:

**index.php file**

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    $thumbnailBgImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');

  <!-- THUMBNAIL SECTION -->
  <div class="post" onclick="openModal('<?php echo $thumbnailBgImg[0] ?>', '<?php the_title(); ?>', '<?php echo $post->ID ?>', '<?php echo the_content() ?>')" >
    <div class="post-thumbnail" id="post-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumbnailBgImg[0]; ?>');"></div>
    <div class="post-content">
      <h3 id="thumbnail-h3"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <p id="thumbnail-p"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- MODAL SECTION -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-box">
      <img class="modal-content" id="modal-img">
    </div>
    <div id="caption">
      <div class="caption-text">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <a></a>
    </div>
  </div>

 endif; endwhile;
endif;
```

**script.js file**

```
// MODAL IMAGE
function openModal(URL, TITLE, ID, CAPTION){
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal')
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("modal-img")
  var caption = document.getElementById("caption")
  var captionH3 = caption.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0]
  var captionA = caption.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
  var captionB = caption.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]

  var newTitle = encodeURIComponent(TITLE.trim())
  modal.style.display = "flex"
  captionH3.innerHTML = TITLE
  modalImg.src = URL
  captionB.innerHTML = CAPTION

  captionA.href = "mailto:josefineklundmail@gmail.com?Subject=" + newTitle
  captionA.innerHTML = "Contact me"

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

My result:

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps <3

Comment: I'm so sorry, I just realized I never replied to you! Thank you for taking the time to post your detailed answer! :)

Comment: @Soph87 No problem - hope it helped a little!

Comment: @Soph87 If it helped you it would be great if you upvoted my answer!

Comment: Done :) Thank you again.